# Help with the lua-visual-debug package

Tags: luatex, debugging

The documentation for [`lua-visual-debug`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug) is a little sparse. Can someone interpret the boxes/lines/colors that `lua-visual-debug` produces?

Comment: Patrick Gundlach promised to improve the documentation when I asked him in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com:80/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).

Comment: Give me a few hours... If someone enhances the documentation, I'll add a 100 bounty to the question.

Comment: A new package (documentation update) is on its way to ctan/texlive.

Comment: Patrick - I apologize if this sounded like a criticism. In all honesty I figured the lack of documentation was a reflection of how little i know about luatex. thanks for the package...

Comment: I didn't take that as criticism, the lack of that part in the documentation was obvious and therefore it sucked. No way put this in nice words. I saw your question as "hey someone is actually using the package and you've always wanted to enhance the doc". So I am grateful for the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: lua-visual-debug detail]

1. A vertical glue. Beginning and end are marked with a small tick. At the mark 1 two vertical glues are connected.
2. A horizontal glue.
3. A negative kern. Positive kerns are yellow.
4. A possible hyphenation point.
5. Horizontal and vertical boxes are drawn with a border.
6. Penalties are marked with a square. A penalty of 10,000 is marked with a blank square, a penalty less than 10,000 is filled with a gray square (that will improve in the future, currently it is grayness of penalty / 10000).

A strut box (zero width box) is marked with a red rule:

[image: strutbox]

Comment: After the "Hello" word in the second image, there is a blue "dotted" line. It looks like the violet "dotted" line in the first image (2: A horizontal glue) - but does it also have the same meaning? The blue in first image is "4. A possible hyphenation point.", but that cannot be the meaning of the blue line after the "Hello" on second image. Can you please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: @sdaau this blue dotted line is a glue and has the same meaning as 2) a horizontal glue. I don't know where the different colors come from.

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying, @PatrickGundlach - cheers!