# Visual debugging of lengths in paragraphs and environments?

Tags: lengths, debugging

During my searches, I found a couple of online images, which I doubt are produced with Latex - however, I found them immensely useful in understanding what is going on.

I'm pretty sure the images below were not produced automatically by latex - so I was wandering if there is a Latex package (or a method) - that would visualize demanded lengths with arrows (*and possibly even length values?*), like on the images below (*apparently, adding them from web adds a copy on imgur; I've added the original links as well*).

In the cases below, they are related to lists (enumerate/itemize) parameters - but I'd be interested in visualizing `\parindent` or `\parskip` in context of paragraphs as well.

- [Fig_enumerateS.jpg](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_c-x8pSJkzrQ/TAnpLG5v8mI/AAAAAAAAAxI/XnmDZlpHUbE/Fig_enumerateS.jpg)

[image: Fig_enumerateS.jpg]

- [listaparametrit.gif](http://mtl.uta.fi/Opetus/LaTeX/images/listaparametrit.gif):

[image: listaparametrit.gif]

- [listparams.png](http://tauros.ams.eng.osaka-u.ac.jp/mt/jp/ANimages/listparams.png)

[image: listparams.png]

Would there be anything out there that allows for similar visualization (*possibly one that would work on a 'per page request' basis too; wouldn't want a 100 pg .pdf choke full with arrow vectors on every paragraph `:)`*)

Comment: Have a look at the package [`layouts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts). However the colored images are made by tikz or pstricks (I guess).

Comment: Many thanks for that @MarcoDaniel - just looking at the package, looks like exactly what I need! Would you mind converting your comment to an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but if you use LuaTeX you can have a look at the lua-visual-debug package. It might give you a feeling where spaces/glues/... are. See  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50964/help-with-the-lua-visual-debug-package

Comment: Many thanks for that, @PatrickGundlach - never heard about that package before, and it has exactly the kind of visualization I want (but I also want marking of lengths as in `layouts`). Wish I could use `lua-visual-debug` with plain `pdflatex` - but it's great to know about it in any case... Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One default package to display length is the package [`layouts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts). It produces black/white images with represented lengths.

For example the example below produces the following images for list-environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}
\listdiagram
\end{document}
```

However the coloured images are probably made by packages like TikZ or PSTricks.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @MarcoDaniel - great to have a minimal example! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, just thought I might also post this snippet here - not quite like `layouts`, this snippet creates a command `\showpagemarginstwh` which only shows the page margins (based on `\textwidth` and `\textheight`) using [LaTeX \put](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_44.html) command:

```
\newlength{\tmvx}
\newlength{\tmvy}
\newlength{\curposy}
\newcommand{\showpagemarginstwh}{%
  \setlength{\curposy}{\dimexpr\pagetotal+\baselineskip}
  %\typeout{\the\curposy}
  \edef\mw{\getlength{\textwidth}}
  \edef\mh{\getlength{\textheight}}
  \edef\mp{\getlength{\parindent}}
  \setlength{\tmvx}{\textwidth}
  %\addtolength{\tmvx}{-\parindent} % use offset
  \setlength{\tmvy}{0.45\textheight}
  \edef\mvx{\getlength{\tmvx}}
  \edef\mvy{\getlength{\curposy}}
  %\begin{picture}(width,height)(x-offset,y-offset)
  \begin{picture}(0,0)(\mp,-\mvy)
    \put(0,0) {\line(1,0){\mw}}
    \put(0,0) {\line(0,-1){\mh}}
    \put(\mvx,0) {\line(0,-1){\mh}}
    \put(0,-\mh) {\line(1,0){\mw}}
  \end{picture}
}
```

Below is an MWE, which generates the following two pages of output:

[image: test.png]

The code (inline links: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55852/2595),
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15002/2595),
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56058/2595),
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/2595),
[5](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13098)
):

```
\documentclass{article}
% reminder: US letter: 596pt x 795pt

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55852/2595
\newlength{\pagewidthA}\newlength{\pageheightA}
\setlength{\pagewidthA}{300bp}\setlength{\pageheightA}{400bp}

\newlength{\pagewidthB}\newlength{\pageheightB}
\setlength{\pagewidthB}{400bp}\setlength{\pageheightB}{500bp}

\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\generatePageLayouts}{%
  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthA,layoutheight=\pageheightA,left=5mm,right=1mm,bottom=12mm,top=1mm}
  \savegeometry{LayoutPageA}

  \newgeometry{layoutwidth=\pagewidthB,layoutheight=\pageheightB,twoside,inner=2.5cm,outer=0.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
  \savegeometry{LayoutPageB}
}

\newcommand{\switchToLayoutPageA}{%
  % doesn't include page sizes; so page size too:
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthA \pdfpageheight=\pageheightA % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthA \paperheight=\pageheightA     % for TikZ
  \loadgeometry{LayoutPageA} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthA \paperheight=\pageheightA     % for TikZ
}

\newcommand{\switchToLayoutPageB}{%
  % doesn't include page sizes; so page size too:
  \pdfpagewidth=\pagewidthB \pdfpageheight=\pageheightB % for PDF output
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthB \paperheight=\pageheightB     % for TikZ
  \loadgeometry{LayoutPageB} % note; \loadgeometry may reset paperwidth/h!
  \paperwidth=\pagewidthB \paperheight=\pageheightB     % for TikZ
}

\usepackage{lipsum}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15002/2595
% to extract numbers from lengths:
% NOTE: \getlength gets numeric portion as pt always;
\makeatletter
  \newcommand*{\getlength}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56058/2595
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/2595
% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13098
%
% display page margins based on \textwidth/height
% note \begin{picture} is treated like character;
% so we "lift" it from current position in page
% to make it align to margins
\newlength{\tmvx}
\newlength{\tmvy}
\newlength{\curposy}
\newcommand{\showpagemarginstwh}{%
  \setlength{\curposy}{\dimexpr\pagetotal+\baselineskip}
  %\typeout{\the\curposy}
  \edef\mw{\getlength{\textwidth}}
  \edef\mh{\getlength{\textheight}}
  \edef\mp{\getlength{\parindent}}
  \setlength{\tmvx}{\textwidth}
  %\addtolength{\tmvx}{-\parindent} % use offset
  \setlength{\tmvy}{0.45\textheight}
  \edef\mvx{\getlength{\tmvx}}
  \edef\mvy{\getlength{\curposy}}
  %\begin{picture}(width,height)(x-offset,y-offset)
  \begin{picture}(0,0)(\mp,-\mvy)
    \put(0,0) {\line(1,0){\mw}}
    \put(0,0) {\line(0,-1){\mh}}
    \put(\mvx,0) {\line(0,-1){\mh}}
    \put(0,-\mh) {\line(1,0){\mw}}
  \end{picture}
}



\begin{document}
  % here geometry layout L1 is instantiated;

  % generate page layouts first based on layoutwidth as page size;
  % don't switch actual page sizes yet:
  \generatePageLayouts{}

  %%% start with content

  % start with LayoutPageA (includes switching page size)
  \switchToLayoutPageA{}

  \lipsum[1]

  \showpagemarginstwh
  \lipsum[2]

  \clearpage

  \switchToLayoutPageB{}

  \lipsum[3]

  \showpagemarginstwh
  \lipsum[4]

  \clearpage

\end{document}
```

Image created with:

```
convert -density 150 -bordercolor LimeGreen -border 2 test.pdf[0] test1.png
convert -density 150 -bordercolor LimeGreen -border 2 test.pdf[1] test2.png
montage test1.png test2.png -geometry +2+2 -tile 2x1 test.png
```