# layouts package reads all length as zero with tikz/fontspec/xelatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, debugging

After getting the suggestion to [use the `layouts` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55618/visual-debugging-of-lengths-in-paragraphs-and-environments) for visual debugging of lengths, I came up with the following example, which I compile with `xelatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem}

\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\pdfpagewidth=148mm \pdfpageheight=210mm % for PDF output
\paperwidth=148mm \paperheight=210mm     % for TikZ


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,yscale=-1,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west]

  \begin{scope}[shift={(-\oddsidemargin,-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\marginparsep)}]% layer1

%   \path[anchor=north west] (0,0) node[below right] (dbg) {% this goes to (0,0) but after margin
  \path[anchor=north west] (current page.north west) node[below right] (dbg) {%
      \begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}%
        \setlayoutscale{1.0} %
        \drawdimensionstrue %
        \pagedesign %
      \end{minipage}
  }%path
  ;

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get as output (*upper/left/right edges of image correlate to corresponding edges of the pdf page*):

[image: test.pdf output]

Notably, all lengths being read are reported as zeroes; I was otherwise hoping that I could force the `layouts` page diagram to be scaled to one, and overlaid over the current page using a tikz node - but that apparently fails.

Is it possible at all that I get a `layouts` page diagram overlaid over a page as I intended to? If so, how?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a bug of `layouts`. The current maintainer of the package is Will Robertson. I think you should send a bug report.

At the moment the following patch using `etoolbox` seems to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\drawpage}{\ifdrawparameters}{\iftrue}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage fixed*******^^J}}%
  {\typeout{^^J*******\string\drawpage not fixed*******^^J}}

\begin{document}
\pagedesign
\end{document}
```

Of course you must setup the tikz environment by your self ;-)

Comment: Many thanks for that, @MarcoDaniel - your fix works great, also for my example above (_to my surprise, with `\setlayoutscale{0.68}`, I get the page edges on layout to scale almost to pdf page edges_). I've seen @WillRobertson around this site, so hopefully tex.se will issue a bump - else, by looking at [CTAN webpage](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/layouts), I should email to submit a bug. Many thanks again - cheers!