# A question about hboxes and vboxes

Tags: boxes

I want to ask if is it possible (if such a process make sense) to print the hboxes and vboxes in order to gain a better understanding of the underfull/overfull hbox/vbox warnings. I use the showframe option of the geometry package but it prints just the bounding frame of each page .. thanks a lot .. Athanasios ...

Comment: there is a luatex visual debug package

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50964/help-with-the-lua-visual-debug-package

Comment: in addition to the luatex package, the usual command I add for any kind of debugging of output is `\showoutput` which puts a full representation of every box into the log

Comment: Every line of text is implemented as an \hbox (hence the overfull or underfull \hbox warning).  Every column of text is implemented and a \vbox (using \unvbox to merge paragraphs and \vsplit at the end of the page).  Every float is a savebox of some sort.  Tabulars are full of \hbox and \vbox to align the rows and columns.  I like to say that the TeX engine basically packs boxes inside other boxes.