# Automatically drawing frames around document elements with LaTeX

Tags: boxes, hooks

I wonder how to draw frames around various elements in LaTeX (or LuaLaTeX if needed)?
I would like to get frames around every text paragraph, and/or every equation, every image, every header, every footer and so on. The frame should identify the bounding box of the object. What is the best way to achieve this? 
I am looking at hooks like `\everyhbox` and `\everyvbox` but I am asking here in case someone had a very clever way to achieve this task.

Best regards,

Fabrice

Comment: lua-visual-debug ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50964/help-with-the-lua-visual-debug-package

Comment: Thanks David! I didn't know about this package. I should be able to tailor it to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lua-visual-debug` package does essentially this (requiring lualatex).